# How to update a single item in flutter list, as a best way

Tags: dart, flutter

How to update a single item in flutter list?

I need best way.

Why I am saying best way?

I need to update a single item and dont want when update a single item on that all items exists in the list get rendered.

I mean when update a single item, then just that single item should be refreshed not the entire list.

because if the entire list gets render for updating just one item, on that time our app may does not have a good performance.

So is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Actually, rebuilding the whole `ListView` does not mean re-rendering the whole list. the `ListView` is a simple data structure. For the items that don't change, their UI elements are not recreated. Don't fight the reactive UI model.

Answer (score 107):

This is my way

```
foods[foods.indexWhere((element) => element.uid == food.uid)] = food;
```

some validation should be applied to avoid any null reference issues

Comment: Could you annotate what exactly is happening with this line? Is `(element) => element.uid` mapping itself? What is being assigned to food in the end?

Comment: lan Smith - `foods` is a `List` which has many `map` typed elements. `food` is the element which has updated values. `foods.indexWhere((element) => element.uid == food.uid)` is being used to get index of element if `element.uid == food.uid` condition is matched then it will return an `index` value like 0 or 1 or something else integer type which is position of updating element in `foods` list. At the end, `foods` list will be updated as per found index eg. `foods[1] = food`. That's it. Thanks for giving me chance to elaborate this answer :)

Comment: How would this work for a nested list of your own type?

Comment: I would add another method if you only need to update one value in one whole element so you don't have to update the whole element

```final index = response.indexWhere((element) => element.id == food.id);```
```response[index] = response[index].copyWith(date: food.date);```

Answer (score 5):

You can do so by nesting a stream builder in each item builder.
This works by using the `initialData` argument of the stream builder.

```
final Stream<Item> updateItemsSteram = ...;
final List<Item> initialList = [...];
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
            return StreamBuilder<Item>(
                initialData: initialList[idx],
                stream: updateItemsSteram.where((item) => item.id == initialList[idx].id),
                builder: (ctx, snapshot) => MyCustomWidget(snapshot.data)
             );
          }
)
```

Though, you may want to benchmark this and compare it to updating the whole list, because flutter reuses the elements in all cases and the streams might just bring more overhead.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem with a statefull widget to represent a item in ListView. If you want manipulate just a item data, you do it by Item widget. If you add or remove a item on the tail of list, the list will be not rerendered.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

RandomColor randomColor = RandomColor();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random(); // Add this line.
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Numbers(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

/**
 * View
 */
class Numbers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return NumbersState();
  }
}

/**
 * Item
 */
class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  int value;

  Item({this.value});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ItemState();
  }
}

class ItemState extends State<Item> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: randomColor.randomColor(colorBrightness: ColorBrightness.light),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(widget.value.toString()),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            widget.value++;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

/**
 * List
 */
class NumbersState extends State<Numbers> {
  List<Item> numbers = new List<Item>();
  String message = "Teste";

  void addItem(int v) {

    Item i = Item(value: v,);
    numbers.add(i);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Stream generateNumbers() async* {
    for (int i in List.generate(5, (i) => i)) {
      yield i;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
//    super.initState();
    generateNumbers().listen((dynamic i) {
      print(i);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
        addItem(i);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Add from here...
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                message = "Teste";
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                message = "Teste";
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                message = "Teste";
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              addItem(1);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () {
              numbers.removeAt(numbers.length-1);
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text("Teste de ListView: \n 1. Atualizar item\n 2. Navegação\n 3. Movimento"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: numbers.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                return numbers[i];
                })
          )
        ],
      ),
    ); // ... to here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue because I had a Stream and a listBuilder (inside the stream) and I was annoyed that the scroll was jumping each time I performed an action at the top because I was adding the items again in the stream. So making the item a statefull widget, it's a good way to go!

Answer (score 4):

If you make sure that list contains your target.

```
foods.firstWhere((element) => element.id == searchedId) = food;
```

```
foods[foods.indexWhere((element) => element.uid == food.uid)] = food;
```

If you aren't sure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
  if (foods[i].id != searchedId) continue;
    foods[i] = food;
    break;
}
```

Warning, the `firstWhere` and `indexWhere` can make an error if your target doesn't exist.
or using it before you use these solutions.

```
bool found = foods.contains((food) => food.id == newFood.id);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large number of items, it is fast to use setState() with ListView.builder(). For example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<int> ids = [];
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      ids.add(i);
    }
    new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        ids[4] = 1000;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ids.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
            return ListTile(title: Text('${ids[idx]}'));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check out the [ListView.builder docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer, but this code is still confusing, and my question is how to update a single item from a large list. think like whatsapp, there is a lot messages displayed in the screen and when we send a message and the other person see it then it gets update the message for me which the message has seen using two tick.
and here just the message has seen gets update not all messages every time

Answer (score 1):

Add or update list

```
    newHistoryList.forEach((newOrder) {
      int index = _existingHistoryList.indexWhere((existingOrder) => existingOrder.id == newOrder.id);
      if (index == -1)
        _existingHistoryList.add(newOrder);
      else
        _existingHistoryList[index] = newOrder;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you the know the index then you easily change the value of its corresponding item.. If you don't know the index then first get the index from the value by using `indexOf(E element, [int start = 0])` method. Then change the value as follows..

```
List<int> list = [1, 2];
growableList[0] = 87;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way is list[index]=updatevalue